# Custom Taxonomies not retaining hierarchy while importing from one site to another

Tags: custom-taxonomy, hierarchical

On my site I have a Custom Post Type "listing" which has a hierarchial Taxonomy "local".

The terms in this taxonomy are in the form of States > Cities.

For example "Washington" is a parent term & Arlington, Auburn, Davenport etc could be it's child taxonomies.

Now when I export & import this Custom Post Type to another site, my child level taxonomies become top level taxonomies, they no longer retain the hierarchy.

I have used code in functions.php to create these, no plugins. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where is your code ?

Answer (score 0):

I understand your problem and had to work around it as well: `wp_insert_term()` doesn't handle parent/children connections.

You can check this with the following:

```
$tax = 'category';
$terms = get_terms( array( $tax ) );

$children_to_update = array();

foreach ( $terms as $term )
{
    $checked_term = get_term_by( 'name', $term, $tax );

    // ... retrieve parent here ...

    if ( ! $checked_term )
    {
        $term_data = wp_insert_term(
            $term,
            $tax,
            array( 'parent' => $parent )
        );
        if (
            is_array( $term_data )
            AND ! is_wp_error( $term_data )
            AND '0' !== $parent
        )
            $children_to_update[ $parent ][] = $term_data['term_id'];
    }
}
// inspect result
var_dump( $children_to_update );
```

You will see that it stays empty. The reason is simple: There's an ***Option*** that holds this information. You'll need to update it as well:

```
$option = get_option( "{$tax}_children" );
foreach( $children_to_update as $new_p => $new_c )
{
    if ( ! array_key_exists( $new_p, $option ) )
    {
        $option[ $new_p ] = $new_c;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach ( $new_c as $c )
        {
            if ( ! in_array( $c, $option[ $new_p ] ) )
                $option[ $new_p ][] = $c;
        }
    }
}
update_option( "{$tax}_children", $option );
```

At first I didn't get that the hierarchy didn't work, but when you look at the taxonomy overview page in the admin UI, then you'll see that the terms are not aligned like the should (in child/parent lists).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just imported some blog posts with hierarchial categories and they all turned into top level Categories as well!

Where and how can I use the code that you have provided?

Comment: Ehm... haven't you written a custom importer? Is this a problem with the default importer?

Comment: Yes this is the problem with default importer. 

To test I made 2 test sites, created few sample posts under Hierarchical Categories on one site, export-imported them into another site and I see the Category Hierarchy is lost!

I had no idea WP did this? Can anyone test this phenomenon & prove that I am not crazy!